Disable automatic restarts on Windows Server 2019
Windows Updates just automatically restarted my Windows Server 2019 at an inconvenient time.
How do I make sure it does not happen again?
(Ideally I would want it to specifically ask administrator desktop sessions for permission restart, but not automatically restart)

How you prevent Windows Server 2019 from automatically restarting after installed updates is nearly identical to how you prevent WIndows 10 from automatically installing Windows Updates and eventually rebooting. Have you tried any of those known solutions to your system?

@Ramhound No I have not. But the gpedit.msc No auto-restart with logged on users for scheduled automatic updates installations option as described in https://www.tenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/17530-disable-automatic-reboot-updates.html#post350686 does not exist on my server 2019
